# Regex to extract string between third and fourth underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I use regex to extract the string between the third and fourth underscore in the following example:

```
123456-AB_ABC_ABC123_Extract This_ABCDEFG
```

I tried

```
^(?:[^_]+_){3}([^_]+)
```

But it seems to return all of the characters up to the fourth underscore instead of starting after the third underscore like I imagined. What'd I miss there?

Thanks!

Comment: Split by `_` and get 3rd element from resulting array.

Comment: Access the Group 1 value.

Comment: to begin with yuio use this regxer `^(?:([^_]+)_){4}` https://regex101.com/r/nOgKoE/1

Comment: Good one, @Edward. Alternatively, yuio could use the following regxer (which contains no capture groups) to match the desired text: `(?<=^(?:[^_\n]*_){3})[^_\n]*(?=_)`. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/0kiAkj/1/). Readers: this makes use of the fact that Javascript's regex engine is one of the few that support *variable-length* lookbehinds.

Comment: @anubhava ... note exactly right ... it is the 4th element but the array index is `3`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger: `arr[3]` is actually 4th element and that's what I meant

Comment: split by `^|_` then arr[4]