# Regex get string between intervals underscores

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I've seen a lot of similar questions, but I wasn't able to get the desired output.

I have a string `means_variab_textimput_x2_200.txt` and I want to catch **ONLY** what is between the third and fourth underscores: **textimput**

- I'm using R, `stringr`, I've tried many things, but none solved the issue:

```
my_string <- "means_variab_textimput_x2_200.txt"

str_extract(my_string, '[_]*[^_]*[_]*[^_]*[_]*[^_]*')
"means_variab_textimput"

str_extract(my_string, '^(?:([^_]+)_){4}')
"means_variab_textimput_x2_"
str_extract(my_string, '[_]*[^_]*[_]*[^_]*[_]*[^_]*\\.') ## the closer I got was this
"_textimput_x2_200."
```

- Any ideas? Ps: I'm VERY new to Regex, so details would be much appreciated :)
- additional question: can I also get only a "part" of the word? let's say, instead of **textimput** only **text** but without counting the words? It would be good to know both possibilities
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793950/regex-to-remove-all-text-before-a-character) [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62582196/regex-to-extract-string-between-third-and-fourth-underscore) [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript) were helpful, but I couldn't get the final expected results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may use `str_replace` i.e. `str_replace(my_string, "^[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]+)_.*", "\\1")
[1] "textimput"`

Comment: Or with `base R` `strsplit(my_string, "_")[[1]][3]#
[1] "textimput"`

Comment: Using your methods in `str_extract` is a bit troublesome for extracting from the third word.  Because regex lookaround `(?<=` may need fixed length.  Or we could use perl options (stringr is based on ICU).  i.e. `regmatches(my_string, regexpr("^([^_]+_){2}\\K[^_]+", my_string, perl = TRUE))#
[1] "textimput"`

Comment: thank you very much!! ps: is there a way to extract only "part" of the word (additional q)? I've got that by putting ```str_sub(str_replace(my_string, "^[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]+)_.*", "\\1"), start = 1, end = 4)``` , but is there a more straight-forward way?

Comment: In fact, the idea was to get the whole word, I'm sorry for the confusion (I'm new to the forum, but I'm getting the rhythm), I've put the addition question in a bullet, bad practice?. It's good to have both options! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringr` uses `ICU` based regular expressions.  Therefore, an option would be to use regex lookarounds, but here the length is not fixed, thus `(?<=` wouldn't work.  Another option is to either remove the substrings with `str_remove` or use `str_replace` to match and capture the third word which doesn't have the `_` (`[^_]+`) and replace with the backreference  (`\\1`) of the captured word

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(my_string, "^[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]+)_.*", "\\1") 
[1] "textimput"
```

If we need only the substring

```
str_replace(my_string, "^[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]{4}).*", "\\1") 
[1] "text"
```

---

In `base R`, it is easier with `strsplit` and get the third word with indexing

```
strsplit(my_string, "_")[[1]][3]
# [1] "textimput"
```

Or use `perl = TRUE` in `regexpr`

```
regmatches(my_string, regexpr("^([^_]+_){2}\\K[^_]+", my_string, perl = TRUE))
# [1] "textimput"
```

For the substring

```
regmatches(my_string, regexpr("^([^_]+_){2}\\K[^_]{4}", my_string, perl = TRUE))
[1] "text"
```

Comment: thank you very much! I was trying to do another thing now based on your answer:  ```str_replace(my_string, "^([^_]+)_[^_]+_([^_]+).*", "\\1\\2")
[1] "NARR200" (the string is: NARR_G2_200_AB)```. I wanted "NARR 200 AB" (skipping G2). Where did I get it wrong? @akrun

Comment: I tried to use \\3 too, like ```^([^_]+)_[^_]+_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_.*", "\\1\\2\\3``` , but now I get the whole string

Comment: @LarissaCury Try `str_replace(my_string, "^([^_]+)_[^_]+_([^_]+)_([^_]+)", "\\1 \\2 \\3")#
[1] "NARR 200 AB"` The `.*` at the end is removing the rest of characters.  You need `(.*)`

Comment: thank you VERY much! (once more!). Regex seems to be an amazing tool, I'll work my way through it :)

Comment: Funny thing, I'm using it inside a ```str_glue()``` , ```str_glue("{str_replace(mystring, '^([^_]+)_[^_]+_([^_]+)_([^_]+)', '\\1 \\2 \\3')}")``` . Am I mistyping something? (it works outside glue just fine)

Comment: @LarissaCury I think you need to escape the backreferences i.e. `str_glue("{str_replace(mystring, '^([^_]+)_[^_]+_([^_]+)_([^_]+)', '\\\\1 \\\\2 \\\\3')}") #
NARR 200 AB`

Comment: @LarissaCury Sorry, for the late reply.  I did see your comment, but forgot to reply earlier

Comment: That was a good question as I didn't notice that earlier

Comment: I ended up using paste0 (which I don't like, I personally prefer ```stringr``` 's functions), but then I'll try again with your solution!

Comment: It is just that whenever there is `\\`, it needs escape within the glue

Answer (score 2):

Following up on question asked in comment about restricting the size of the extracted word, this can easily be achieved using quantification. If, for example, you want to extract only the first 4 letters:

```
sub("[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]{4}).*$", "\\1", my_string)
[1] "text"
```