# REGEX to extract a string after an underscore up to a final mark in R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I'm sure this is a silly question, I have a couple of strings such as `data_PB_Belf.csv` and I need to exctract only `PB_Belf` (and so on). **How can I exctract everything after the first _ up to . (preferably using `stringr` ) ?**

```
data
[1] "data_PB_Belf.csv" "data_PB_NI.csv" ...

str_replace(data[1], "^[^_]+_([^_]+)_.*", "\\1") ## the closer I got, it returns "PB"
```

- I tried to adapt the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73939789/regex-get-string-between-intervals-underscores), but I wasn't able to. I'm sure that there's a way to use `str_replace()` or `str_sub()` or `str_extract()`, I just can't get the right Regex. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sidenote: With the `strex` package you could try `str_after_first()` function too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may match the one or more characters that are not a `_` (`[^_]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string, followed by an `_`, then capture the characters that are not a dot (`.`) (`([^.]+)`) followed by `.` (dot is metacharacter, so escape `\\`), followed by any characters and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("^[^_]+_([^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", data)
[1] "PB_Belf" "PB_NI"
```

Or with `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(data, "^[^_]+_([^.]+)\\..*", "\\1")
[1] "PB_Belf" "PB_NI"
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! Would you mind explaining the logic behind it? I couldn't get the right Regex by myself

Comment: @LarissaCury hope the description helps you

Answer (score 1):

There are other, simpler, options available too. For example, you can use, as you mentioned, `str_extract` in conjunction with lookarounds:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=_).*?(?=\\.)")
[1] "PB_Belf" "PB_NI"
```

Here we are using:

- `(?<=_)`: positive look behind to assert that what we want to extract must be preceded by `_` and
- `(?=\\.)`: positive look ahead to assert that what we want to extract must be followed by a dot.

Data:

```
x <- c("data_PB_Belf.csv", "data_PB_NI.csv")
```